# Config file Performance question

Tags: asp.net, performance, config, appsettings

I have around 60 web apps on web server, all of these app have some of the same appsetting values in the web.config. These settings are loaded into memory as soon as the application starts. I would like to centralise these values in one config file for all apps to load.

My question is, if i load all of the apps up at the same time, would there be any performance issues accessing this same config file at the same time?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read locks are generally not exclusive so any number of applications can read from the same file at the same time. If you're not specifically requesting read exclusivity, you should be fine.

You should look at how you're loading the configuration file into each application.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, because you need disk IO to access the file. But if the values stay in memory, I would say the performance issue would be minimal afterwards. Just be sure to read out the file without locking it (I believe with the `FileShare.ReadWrite` enum).

Answer (score 0):

You might even see a small performance improvement since the file will be cached by the operation system when the first application reads the file, subsequent files will read directly from memory.

But the only way to know for sure is to measure and see.